# What is more efficient in a table with more than 1 million rows ? Cross join or sub query?

Tags: sql, database, performance

I need to create a view that will filter a date range that is set in only 1 row in an auxiliary table:

`aux_date_table`:

```
start_date     end_date
------------------------
08/01/18       08/11/18
```

`main_table`

```
date        subject
--------------------------
01/08/18    inoninoininoi
01/08/18    inoninoininoi
01/08/18    inoninoininoi
02/08/18    inoninoininoi
02/08/18    inoninoininoi
02/08/18    inoninoininoi
03/08/18    inoninoininoi
03/08/18    inoninoininoi
03/08/18    inoninoininoi
04/08/18    inoninoininoi
.
.
.
```

The first option would be:

```
select main_table.* 
from main_table, aux_date_table
where main_table.date between aux_date_table.start_date 
                          and aux_date_table.end_date
```

The second option would be:

```
select main_table.* 
from main_table
where main_table.date between (select start_date from aux_date_table) 
  and (select end_date from aux_date_table)
```

Which option is the most efficient?

Comment: If the aux_table has a single row, then there's no noticeable difference between both solutions. Use the one that "looks" best to you.

Comment: What is a "MM"?

Comment: Are you missing a `BETWEEN` in your second query?

Comment: MM - Millions    (https://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-does-m-and-mm-stand-for)

@sticky bit - Thanks. Adjusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `JOIN` instead of first option or second option Because that will be more clear what you want to do.

```
select main_table.* from main_table 
INNER JOIN aux_date_table 
ON main_table.data between aux_date_table.start_date and aux_date_table.end_date
```

Your first option is CROSS JOIN but old style.

I would suggest you use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `,`

```
select main_table.* 
from main_table CROSS JOIN aux_date_table
where main_table.data between aux_date_table.start_date and aux_date_table.end_date
```

If you want to choose which one is faster I would choose first option.

Because the second option use subquery in where the `performance` might be worse then first.

Comment: Some DBMS's do not support `CROSS JOIN` like MS Access, so must use commas. And from OP's history, OP uses MS Access.

Comment: Perfect @Parfait!